# Mobile off canvas menu not working

Tags: templates, menu, mobile-web-design

I'm having difficulty getting the off canvas menu to work on a mobile view.
I am using a LT Social theme template, my web address is [gracegarton.com.au](http://gracegarton.com.au/)
I had it working a week ago, but went to tweak it and screwed it up somehow.

Comment: Can you describe for us what tweaks you made and/or which files you were tweaking?  Please take the [tour] while you wait for support.

Comment: Using the console in firefox developer tools, I can see a tonne of Content Security Policy errors that are causing scripts not to load. I would try fixing them first (they are all being caused by the same problem). If you are lucky that will fix the menu problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a warning being displayed

> Please publish modules in **offcanvas** position

but you can't see because it is off the canvas!

Otherwise there is no content (e.g. a menu) to be displayed.

```
<div class="offcanvas-menu">
    <a href="#" class="close-offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
    <div class="offcanvas-inner">
        <p class="alert alert-warning">Please publish modules in <strong>offcanvas</strong> position.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```